# Strange primefaces horizontal bar behaviour

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I need your help to understand a very strange primefaces horizontal bar behaviour.

What I'd like to do is to draw a horizontal bar with primefaces.

Here are all my datas I get from my postgresql db table:

[image: table]

For the following explanations please refer to this horbarchart image: 
[image: horbarchart]

If I get only first five banks from my db everything's ok! (1)

If I try to get and show all the banks disaster happens :( Only eight banks are shown and values are shifted. (2)

Finally, if I try to get and show the last four banks only two are shown with wrong values. (3)

Obviously, I checked with my debugger's IDE if every chart serie was populated correctly and everything is build in a very right way.

This is my (hibernate) class that gets datas from db:

```
public class ChartRequestTypeJPA {
static final transient Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ChartRequestTypeJPA.class.getName());
static final transient ResourceBundle BUNDLE = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getResourceBundle(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "txt");

public List<ChartRequestType> getAll(TimeInterval step) throws Exception { 
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Criteria criteria = session
                .createCriteria(ChartRequestType.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("pk.step", step.getDescr()));
        List<ChartRequestType> result = criteria.list();

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Error getting chart request type" + e.getMessage());
        throw new DMLException(BUNDLE.getString("message.noDataFound"));
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my class that sets the bar chart model:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Chart11RequestTypeView {  
    private HorizontalBarChartModel chartRequestTypeModel;

    private void createHorizontalBarModel() {
    chartRequestTypeModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel();

    ChartSeries informazioni = new ChartSeries();
    ChartSeries anomalia = new ChartSeries();
    ChartSeries rio = new ChartSeries();        

    // Valori percentuali della singola banca sul totale letto da oracle
    informazioni.setLabel(TXT.getString("uilabel.chart11.informazioni"));
    anomalia.setLabel(TXT.getString("uilabel.chart11.anomalia"));
    rio.setLabel(TXT.getString("uilabel.chart11.rio"));
    int size = chartRequestType.size();   

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String tipologia = chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getTipologia();
        String bankName = chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getName();
        int tickNumb = chartRequestType.get(i).getTicketnumber();

        switch(tipologia){
            case "Anomalia":{
                anomalia.set(bankName, (int) tickNumb);
                break;
            }
            case "Informazioni":{
                informazioni.set(bankName, (int) tickNumb);

                break;
            }
            case "Richiesta Operativa":{
                rio.set(bankName, (int)tickNumb);

                break;
            }
        }

        if(chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getTipologia().equals("Informazioni")){
            informazioni.set(chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getName(), chartRequestType.get(i).getTicketnumber());
        }
        if(chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getTipologia().equals("Anomalia")){
            anomalia.set(chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getName(), chartRequestType.get(i).getTicketnumber());
        }
        if(chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getTipologia().equals("Richiesta Operativa")){
            rio.set(chartRequestType.get(i).getPk().getName(), chartRequestType.get(i).getTicketnumber());
        }
    }

    chartRequestTypeModel.setSeriesColors("999999,666666,333333");
    chartRequestTypeModel.setTitle(TXT.getString("uilabel.chart11.title"));

    chartRequestTypeModel.addSeries(anomalia);
    chartRequestTypeModel.addSeries(informazioni);
    chartRequestTypeModel.addSeries(rio);

    Axis xAxis = chartRequestTypeModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setLabel(TXT.getString("uilabel.chart11.number"));
    xAxis.setMin(0);
    xAxis.setTickAngle(40);
    xAxis.setTickFormat("%d");

    chartRequestTypeModel.setExtender("chartRequestTypeExtender");
    // horizontalBarModel.setShowPointLabels(true); qui non serve, sta nell'extender
}

}
```

Finally, this is my xhtml:

```
<p:panel style="text-align: center; width:100%; border: 0px;">
    <p:panelGrid id="pchart11" columns="1" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom:10px; width: 100%; height:600px;">
        <p:row>
            <p:chart type="bar" model="#{chart11RequestTypeView.chartRequestTypeModel}" style="height:600px;" />
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function chartRequestTypeExtender() {
        this.cfg.sortData = true; // forse superfluo
        this.cfg.legend = {
            show: true,
            location: 'e',
            placement: 'insideGrid'
        };
        this.cfg.grid = {
            background: 'transparent',
            gridLineColor: '#D0D0FF',
            drawBorder: false
        };
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        // Show point labels to the right ('e'ast) of each bar.
        // edgeTolerance of -15 allows labels flow outside the grid
        // up to 15 pixels.  If they flow out more than that, they 
        // will be hidden.
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
        // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
            shadowAngle: 135,
        // Here's where we tell the chart it is oriented horizontally.
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            }
    };
    this.cfg.highlighter = {
            show: true,
            tooltipAxes: 'x', // da usare anche in altri chart, evita l'ambiguita dei tootips tipo 3,7 inteso come 3.7 anzichè valore 7 per il punto 3
            useAxesFormatters: false,
            tooltipFormatString: "%i"};
}
</script> 
</html>
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you so much for listening me

Comment: Why are you using a panelGrid with one column? Can't you omit that? Primefaces layout components are iffy sometimes and certain css, layouts and functionality will break seemingly at random because of this, I've had many issues with the `<p:layoutUnit>` components in that regard. Also check if your HorizonalBar works with other types of components. The `<p:chart>` uses HTML5 Canvas for drawing, maybe that's why it is breaking?

Comment: Thank you for repling, your suggest was precious! I removed every primefaces <p> tag except for <p:chart>. Now first eight banks are shown with right values! This is a first step but last two banks still aren't shown. Any other ideas?

Comment: Like I said, try the horizontal slider with other elements such as simple `<div>`s to see if it's a problem with how primefaces generates components or not. Maybe you also want to generate a `<div>` where ALL components are rendered on page load, with `overflow: hidden` set as style. If you don't HAVE to use your custom scrollbar, you could also try `overflow: scroll` for style.

Comment: Unfortunately also without primefaces component sometimes it works showing only eight banks with right values and sometimes it doesn't, showing wrong values :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Primefaces barcharts need to have the same number of values for every ChartSeries to format them correctly. I populate my three series with different number of values for every bank; this was the problem!

So, be careful to populate every ChartSeries with the same number of values.

Enojoy! :)